# Display text from a mysql table like a array

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
 mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page where page_id = '$page_id'") or die(mysql_error());

while($land = mysql_fetch_array($resultxx)){

$land =$land['land'];

?>
```

output `$land` is `NL,DE,BE,AL..`
How is it possible to splits the output

example

```
<?php 
      echo "    
    <select> 
    <option value='NL'>NL</option>
    <option value='DE'>DE</option>
    <option value='BE'>BE</option>
    <option value='AL'>AL</option>
    </select>";

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: `$exp = explode(',', $land);` and get with `echo $exp[0];` [explode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: This question is very vague.  The content of $land['land'] = "NL, DE, BE, AL"?  Is that what you are saying? OR that the content of $land['land'] = "NL" for one record, "DE" for another, etc.?  If it's the first, just use [explode(',', $land);](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: Try `echo implode(' ',explode(',',$land['land']));`.

Comment: i have problems with editing above. but what i mean NL DE BE AL they are <option>NL</option>.......

Comment: $exp[0] shows only the first one. how can i put this into a while loop and display all.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
<?php
 mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page where page_id = '$page_id'") or die(mysql_error());

while($land = mysql_fetch_array($resultxx)){

$land =$land['land'];
$landarray = explode(",",$land);
$count = count($landarray);
echo "<select>";
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
echo '<option value='.$landarray[$i].'>'.$landarray[$i].'</option>';
}
echo "</select>";
}

?>
```